# Extend Underscore.js with `_.mixin()` while keeping the original functionality

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using `_.mixin()` to add additional functionality to some of the functions in Underscore.js. What I want to do is overload the call so that when the original signature is being used the original Underscore function is called. However it's oddly difficult to keep a reference to the original function. I've tried multiple ways to keep the original reference only to find once `_.mixin()` is applied the reference points to the new function.

```
(function() {
  //Just using the base underscore pattern
  var root = this;
  
  //Save a object reference to the old function
  var _oldCall = root._.oldCall;
  root._.mixin({
    oldCall: function (list, funk) {
      //Call old function when we detect we should
      if(/*detect old signature*/) return _oldCall(list, funk);
      
      //Otherwise do something else
      return 'something else';
    }
  });
}).call(this)
```

What ends up happening is that an exception is thrown as the call enters an infinite loop, and ends when the stack can push no more function calls. Where how is the reference to the old function being replaced?

## Edit

Based on the submitted answers I built a proof of concept for @Simon Boudrias. One with just a clone. Another where i try to replace the value of _ with the clone. The first example works as expected, the second one blows my mind but is what i'm seeing when i try to keep an unmodified reference around.

### [Copy _, extend _, revert _ from copy](http://jsbin.com/aLATEhI/2/edit?js,console)

```
var c = _.clone(_);

c.max(); //-Infinity
_.max()) //-Infinity

_.mixin({'max': function () {return 'whole bunches';}});

c.max(); //-Infinity
_.max(); //'whole bunches'

_ = c;

c.max(); //-Infinity
_.max(); //-Infinity
```

### [Backup Underscore, copy underscore and assign _ the copy, extend _, then restore _ from backup](http://jsbin.com/UNOwAbuG/1/edit?js,console)

```
var backup = _;
var c = _.clone(_);
_ = c;

backup.max(); // -Infinity
_.max(); // -Infinity

_.mixin({'max': function () {return 'whole bunches';}};

backup.max(); // 'whole bunches'
_.max(); // -Infinity

_ = backup;

backup.max(); // 'whole bunches'
_.max(); // 'whole bunches'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, the code seems ok. The only thing is you should probably make sure the context is kept when calling the old method: `_oldCall.call(root._, list, funk)`.

Still, this can bring weird behavior if methods are recursive (which seems to be the case here).

This is one of the reason why modifying and object you don't own is usually a bad idea.

To achieve similar results, I belive you should provide a façade. Either to the full underscore API, or to only the method you whish to modify.

```
var raw_ = root._;
var my_ = _.clone(root._); // Consider this pseudo code, I don't think _ clone deeply

my_.myOverride = function() {
    // call the raw_ methods when necessary here
};

// Then export your underscore with your usual module system or global
export._ = my_;
// root.my_ = my_
```

Or simply make your own methods and import it when necessary:

```
exports = function() {
    // my functions with call to _
}
```

Comment: Liked this and gave it a shot. Worked till I tried to keep a backup around and use it later. Left some code examples.

Comment: Thing is underscore keep a local (private) reference to itself in it's closure. So when you call `_.mixin`, this reference is updated. So every copy also get the same modifications. IMO, you should only overide the method directly, e.g.: `_.max = function() {}`

Comment: I love the idea of making an extension transparent, eg. new features that fall back to the original use in that context. However it will just be easier to build the lib as a stand alone object.

Answer (score 1):

i have tested your code `http://jsfiddle.net/WLCcd/` , and it shows that the original reference is kept, so look for error in other place

```
(function() {
  //Just using the base underscore pattern
  var root = this;

    root._.mixin({
    oldCall: function () {
      console.log('old');
    }
    });
  //Save a object reference to the old function

        var _oldCall = root._.oldCall;
    //delete root._.oldCall;
  root._.mixin({
    oldCall: function (list, funk) {
      if(arguments.length == 0) return _oldCall();
 console.log('new');
      //Otherwise do something else
      return 'something else';
    }
  });
    console.dir(_oldCall);
    _.oldCall();
    _.oldCall(1);
}).call(this)
```